# Manual Partitioning During Installation: Understanding File System Types

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, filesystem, ext4, reiserfs

I am wondering if anyone can help me understand the difference(s) between the different file system types:  ie. swap, ext4, reiserfs, etc...  I am working with the manual partitioning during installation process for Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

I read step-by-step instructions regarding the process of using manual partitioning during installation, but I found some of what I read to be a bit confusing.

For example, it was suggested to set "/" root fs to ext4.  These instructions continued to say that "/home", "/boot", "/tmp", and "/var" partitions also be set to ext4.  However, slightly contradicting its previous statements, these instructions said that "/home" could also be set as reiserfs--stating that it is a quicker type, but that ext4 was more flexible.

Considering that I am a first-time user, having prior experience only with Windows OS, these are all extremely foreign to me.  What file type(s) should I set these partitions to in order to achieve optimal system performance?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Do I use ext4 for all partitions (such as / and /boot)? What are the other formats used for?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/337196/do-i-use-ext4-for-all-partitions-such-as-and-boot-what-are-the-other-forma)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ext4 is the default and most widely used on Ubuntu. As a fairly new user, it's the one I've used most often.

There's a good overview of file system types, on the ubuntu help pages [here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxFilesystemsExplained).

Have fun!